# Word to signify a Date to compare against

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that describes a significant event in a timeline. A date used in comparing pre and post events/data. Some of the following words are close but not quite right:

**Inaugural | Commencement**

Really close but I'm looking for more comparison

**Reference Point | Comparison Date | Effective Date**

Two words, but close. It's missing the "significant event" feeling

**Incident | Occasion**

Focused too much on the thing vs a date to compare other things to

**Pivotal**

Too strong, looking for more, this happened and we should use that as the baseline

**Baseline**

Is there a date word for this?

Comment: Sounds like a milestone. That serves as a landmark.

Comment: Are you thinking of events like paying off your mortgage or your business becoming profitable? The sort of thing that's important but doesn't actually make that much difference to your day-to-day life. The examples I've given are less obviously significant than graduation, marriage or the establishment of a business for example as they are not obvious to other people at the time.

Comment: Well NASA uses the evocative *T* as in *T minus three days, four hours and twenty-four minutes* ... *T plus 5 seconds*, and so forth.  *T==0* usually marks a significant event 

Comment: You should give some context in a sample sentence (using a blank for your word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Epochal*** events are those that are 'so important and significant they have the power to usher in a new epoch. In other words they're "epoch-making" ' *(vocabulary.com)*. An ' "epoch" serves as a reference point from which time is measured' *(wikipedia)*.

Comment: Epoch seems an ideal word with the right meaning, but annoyingly it is often used in an extended (or incorrect) way just to mean any long period of time. See the definitions in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epoch), where meanings 1a and 3 have the specific meaning of a point in time used for measurement or to inaugurate a new age, but 1b and 2 are the extended/weakened meanings.

Answer (score 1):

**Milepost**

Or in some contexts:

**Watershed**

Examples:

*My boss told me today I've met my first three mileposts.*

*I see a shift in my son's attitude toward college.  I think that super positive email from his winter session instructor was a watershed event.*

Not the greatest examples but really, you should be giving us the examples so we can plug in the puzzle piece.

If you edit your question to fit the site standards I'll go to the trouble of giving you links to helpful dictionary entries.

Answer (score 0):

You might try ***watershed moment***

Defined by [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/idiom/watershed-moment/)

> A watershed moment is a turning point, the exact moment that changes the direction of an activity or situation. A watershed moment is a dividing point, from which things will never be the same. It is considered momentous, though a watershed moment is often recognized in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

**anchor / anchor date** (n.)

**anchor**

A reliable or principal support : MAINSTAY

---

> In this example, we have another procedure for calculating dates,
> based on the use of an "**anchor date**". [A. Collins and D. Bobrow;
> *Representation and Understanding*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Representation_and_Understanding/JImLBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22anchor%20date%22%20important&pg=PA206&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> That's a pretty simple **anchor date** for me to remember as I get
> older and things that once were important aren't anymore. It was an
> exciting time in both our lives. [Ira Wagler; *Broken Roads*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Broken_Roads/QvysDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22anchor%20date%22%20important&pg=PT70&printsec=frontcover)
> (2020)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'inflection point' comes to mind as in: "The day my boyfriend lied to me was an **inflection point** in our relationship. After that, I just didn't know if I could believe anything he said."

In mathematics, an inflection point is the point on a curve where the change in slope switches from a slope that is increasing to a slope that is decreasing, as in a typical s-curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

“How the government of Haiti moves forward after February 7, the official end of assassinated President Jovenel Moïse’s term, will be an important **inflection point** for Ariel Henry’s government and its ability to bring some measure of political stability to Haiti,” a U.S. intelligence official told McClatchy.
(https://www.mcclatchydc.com/news/politics-government/white-house/article257283037.html)

"An **inflection point** is an event that results in a significant change in the progress of a company, industry, sector, economy, or geopolitical situation and can be considered a turning point after which a dramatic change, with either positive or negative results, is expected to result." (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inflectionpoint.asp)

The electrification in the last mile mobility segment (including two- and three-wheelers) has reached an **inflection point**, said Suman Mishra, chief executive, Mahindra Electric Mobility (MEB). “It was 2 per cent last year, 7 per cent this year and would easily reach 30 per cent penetration level by 2025 if there are no major changes,” said Mishra.
(https://wap.business-standard.com/article/automobile/electrification-in-last-mile-mobility-now-at-inflection-point-meb-head-121121601107_1.html)

Comment: Hello, Mylo. ELU examines standard usages; whimsical, creative metaphors belong rather on Literature.SE or Writing.SE. If you have plenty of reputable sources using this expression in this way, please add a few and this will be seen to be a valid answer here.